# Lotus Notes: How to show up Rich Text Field in a view? For existing documents

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have some Rich Text Fields in a form definition. It is really just Text. I want to show it in a view but cannot find the field when I add a new Column.

I searched a lot and find out that Rich Text cannot be shown up directly in a view.

Then I found this idea to have a hidden field as a computed field with formula defined as 
@Abstract([TextOnly];60400;"","FieldName")

But this only works if a new document is created or changes are made for a document. 
I have almost over 25k documents and it is not practical to do that manually.

Is there anyway to make the hidden computed field got recalculated? Or any other way to show a Rich Text Field in a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an Agent witch runs over all documents in view with the following code:

```
        Dim session as new notessession
    dim db as notesdatabase
    dim view as notesview
    dim doc as notesdocument

    set db = session.currentdatabase
    set view = db.getview("")
    set doc = view.getfirstdocument()
    while not doc is nothing
        Call doc.computewithform(true, false)
        Call doc.save(true,true)

        Set doc = view.getnextdocument(doc)
    wend
```

But with running this agent you will change the last modified date of the documents. If it is important to save the date you can write it in an other field and display it.

Comment: Do I have to create an Agent? Can I just create a form with a button. And then add the code in the button click event. And then preview in Notes and Click the button?  I am really new to Lotus Notes. I am not sure if it has to be an Agent

Comment: You can do it in both way. But if there are many documents in view, you should use an agent and trigger it to run on server, this is much faster

Comment: Actually I am doing it in the way I said. I am testing with 10 documents. But with the code above. It is not working.

Comment: I tried with Agent way and it works. I am still confused about all this. I have tested with that in a button click but no luck. I think the only difference might be that Instead of iterating over a view. I used db.allDocuments to get all documents. But I don't think that might be the reason why it does not work in the first place.

Comment: Use db.alldocuments only when you are sure that you want to change all documents of database and not only documents of one view

Comment: I tested the version with the code in the button and it also works for me, but is very slow with many documents

Comment: Although this method usually works, it can be a problem if any documents have field values that would fail validation.

Comment: Because of this Error Handling with logging is a solution

Answer (score 4):

You have a hidden field already which gets the text only part of the RichText field. That works for new documents or documents which got edited.

Write a formula agent which sets the hidden field to all other documents. It would have a formula

```
SELECT @All; 
FIELD FieldNameTextOnly := @Abstract([TextOnly]; 2000; ""; "FieldName");
""
```

and the Target option "All documents in view". Go to the view which contains all 25k documents and start the agent.

Then add a column for your hidden field "FieldNameTextOnly" to your view if you haven't already.

Be a bit careful with the number of characters you want to get from RichText field as those will be part of calculated view so the view might get very large ...

Comment: Create the agent in Designer with menu "Create\Design\Agent" and choose type "Formula".

Comment: I am quite new to Lotus Notes. I have created an Agent. Do you know how to run it?

Comment: Run agent in Notes Client (not Designer) with menu "Actions\yourAgentName". Open the view with your documents before.

Comment: Yep. It works.  Thanks a lot. But actually I haven't tried your suggestion. I have achieved my goal using poisonedYouth's way.  I put the similar code in a agent. And it works.  Actually, I have tried a lot of ways, but all in a button click event. Do you think it makes difference if it's in a button click or an agent?

Comment: It does work in a button click event only if you select target option "All documents in database" for formula agents OR in addtion "None" for LotusScript agents.

Comment: The disadvantage of `computewithform` solution is that it is very slow and in some cases ruins documents (e.g. if you use calculated docID fields for links)

Comment: The other disadvantage of ComputeWithForm is that validation formulas might fail if some docs were saved before changes were made to the form.

Comment: The code snippet you posted above. Is that supposed to be written inside of a Agent? More specifically in the Sub Initialize()?  Cause when I put SELECT @all; It says error on that.

Comment: Like I described in my first comment: agent type has to be "Formula". You can choose the type only during creating an agent Then code above will be accepted und work.